# I have problem when I want debug my app in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

Error:

> adb: failed to install C:\Users\legion\Desktop\nojoum-application\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl764320653.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #79): com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioService: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]
> Error launching application on sdk gphone64 x86 64.

This is my error log:

[image: this is my error log]

Comment: Add your manifest to this question

Answer (score 0):

Please add the

```xml
android:exported="true"
```

to your Main Activity's `activity` tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, like this:

1. Open Your Project's Android manifest, located at `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`
2. Go to this line: `android:name=".MainActivity"`
3. Below this line, add `android:exported="true"`

The code should now look like this:

```
android:name=".MainActivity" // this must be the main activity
android:exported="true"
android:launchMode="singleTop" // this line can be something else, no worries
```

## Explanation

What this does is that it tells Android to make this activity available to be accessed by another app, so that it can open your App. As the launcher (the app drawer/home screen) can be a normal app in android, the Main Activity must be exported to allow it to launch your app.

Answer (score 0):

Go to android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml and paste `android:exported="true"` after `android:name=".MainActivity"` like this:

[image]